# US Student debt volume and default rate data source

Tags: data-request

I would like to see data for private and public student loans and their default rate over time

Comment: You should specify the country/countries you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your title, I assume you're looking for data for the US. This [report from the U.S. Department of Education](https://nces.ed.gov/pubs2018/2018410.pdf) presents data and selected findings about the repayment of **federal student loans** using data from the 2015 Federal Student Aid Supplements to two Beginning Postsecondary Students Longitudinal Studies (BPS).

The report focuses on two cohorts of borrowers: those who began their postsecondary education in the 1995–96 academic year (BPS:96/01) and those who began in the 2003–04 academic year (BPS:04/09).

The report presents estimates of both cohorts' cumulative borrowing, repayment, and **default** statuses as of June 30, 2015, some 20 years after the 1995–96 cohort and 12 years after the 2003–04 cohort began postsecondary education.

### Interesting key findings

- Some 55% of students in the 1995–96 cohort and 63% of the 2003–04 cohorttook out federal education loans within 12 years of entering postsecondary education.
- Overall, 25% of borrowers in the 1995–96 cohort had defaulted on at least one loan within 20 years of beginning postsecondary education, and 14% defaulted on their most recent loan.
- Among borrowers in the 2003–04 cohort, 45% of those who had never attained a credential and were not enrolled in 2009 had defaulted on a loan within 12 years. Among those who attained undergraduate certificates, the rate of defaulting within 12 years was 44%; for associate's degree recipients, it was 22%; and for bachelor's degree recipients, it was 8%.